# Can an incapacitated character still use bonus actions?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, bonus-action

The [Incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) condition says:

> An incapacitated creature can’t take actions or reactions.

Can someone who is incapacitated still take bonus actions?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### No, an incapacitated character cannot take bonus actions.

From the rules for [bonus actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions):

> anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action.

And as you have observed, being [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) deprives you of your ability to take actions:

> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.